# Get DHCP IP from ISP

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

How can I give the interface gi0/0 on router4 a IP with dhcp from the router ISP_RECHTS?

Current Config

ISP_RECHTS config:

```
ip dhcp pool EINS
 network 70.0.1.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 70.0.1.1

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 70.0.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
```

Router4:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 duplex auto
 speed auto
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that config snippet to work, everything between the two routers has to be 100% layer-2 transparent. The broadcast probes from R4 have to be seen as-is on ISP_RECHTS g0/1. (as if they're one LAN)

In more complex networks, the DHCP server doesn't live directly on the segments with clients. In this case, dhcp relay is setup somewhere in each LAN to carry the traffic to/from the foreign DHCP server. The relay agent fills in fields allowing the server to know which pool is appropriate -- i.e. a LAN other than one of the servers directly connected networks (where it should hear the broadcast traffic already.)